# NVIDIA Nsight waring: OpenACC injection initialization failed. Is the PGI runtime version greater than 15.7?

Tags: nvidia, nsight, openacc, pgi

I am trying to venture into accelerating my Fortran 2003 programs with OpenACC directives on my Ubuntu 18.04. workstation with Nvidia GeForce RTX 2070 card.  To that end, I have installed Nvidia HPC-SDK version 20.7 which should comes with compilers I need (Fortran 2003 from Portland Group and Nvidia (both are version 20.7-0)) as well as profilers (nvprof and Nvidia Nsight Sytems (2020.3.1)).

After a few post-installation glitches, and owing mostly to the help from Robert Cravella (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695960/robert-crovella) and Mat Colgrove (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3204484/mat-colgrove) I managed to get things going which made me very happy.

My workflow looks like this:

Compile my program:

```
pgfortran -acc -Minfo=accel -o my_program ./my_program.f90
```

I run it through profiler:

```
nsys profile ./my_program
```

And then import into `nsight-sys` with `File -> Open` and chose `report1.qdrep`

I believe this to be a proper workflow.  However, while opening the report file, `nsight-sys` gives me the warning: "OpenACC injection initialization failed. Is the PGI runtime version greater than 15.7?"  That's quite unfortunate, because I use OpenACC to accelerate my programs.

I am not quite sure what PGI runtime is, nor would I know how to check it or change it?  I assume it is something with Portland Group (compiler), but I use the suite compilers shipped with Nvidia's HPC-SDK, so I wouldn't expect incompatibilities with the profiler tools shipped in the same package.

Is it an option, or possible at all, to update the PGI runtime thing?

And advice, please?

*Cheers*

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as your previous post.  There's a know issue with Nsight-Systems version 2020.3 which may sometimes cause an injection error when profiling OpenACC.  I've been told that this was fixed in version 2020.4, hence the work around would be download and install 2020.4 or use a prior release.

https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-systems

Version 2020.3 is what we shipped with the NVHPC 20.7 SDK.  I'm not sure we have enough time to update to 2020.4 in our upcoming 20.9 release, but if not, we'll bundle it in a later release.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mat,

In the meanwhile I managed to have everything running.  I did as follows:

1. First installed CUDA toolkit, which came with the latest driver for my Nvidia RTX 2070 card, 11.1 to be precise.  It needed a reboot, but that's OK.  For CUDA toolkit to work, I had to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to its libraries.
2. Then I installed Nvidia HPC-SDK, which I needed for Fortran 2003 compiler.
   HPC-SDK is built for CUDA version 11.0 and comes with its own libraries and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should point to its libraries different from CUDA toolkit.
3. But, I kept the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to CUDA toolkit ones, and then compilers and profilers work in perfect harmony :-)

Thanks again, you and Robert helped me big time to get things running.